# cytoscape.js - spacing between nodes

Tags: typescript, cytoscape.js

I am using TypeScript to create a cytoscape graph.  I am looking for a way to increase the spacing between nodes.  I have tried to change the value of `spacingFactor`, but that did not change anything that I can see.

Comment: Can you give us more information please? Which layout do you use? Do you have a snippet? Thanks :)

Comment: I edited my answer, please review it and see if it helps :) thx

Comment: @StephanT. - None of those suggestions helped.  I could not see a significant change in the graph.

Comment: Which layout did you test them with? I tested them all with the defined layout myself and it worked for each layout (if you change the values, the graph does change quite a bit). Either you are using another Layout or you use the wrong values...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It always depends on the layout you use. The following snippet shows you how to use the spacingFactor property, other spacing propertys are found in the [official documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/), normally these things are quite easy to find there. If you specify which layout you want, I can also help you with that specific layout.

**Dagre:**

```
this.cytoscape.layout({
  name: "dagre",
 spacingFactor: 12
}).run();
```

**Concentric:**

```
this.cytoscape.layout({
  name: "concentric",
  minNodeSpacing: 12
}).run();
```

**Cose:**

```
this.cytoscape.layout({
  name: 'cose-bilkent',
  animate: false,
  idealEdgeLength: 200
});
```

**Spread:**

```
this.cytoscape.layout({
   name: 'spread',
   minDist: 20
});
```

**Klay:**

don't use klay

Comment: I have tried `cose`, `dagre`, `spread`, `concentric`, and `klay`, but none seem to be responding to `spacingFactor` changes.

This is how I am adding it to the code...

`this.cytoscape.layout({ name: this.layout, spacingFactor: this.spacingFactor }).run();`

Comment: Well, you have just tried this one property then, dagre for example has a very easy solution to this (rankSep, nodeSep and edgeSep....) I will edit the question with the relevant properties for each of these layouts and remove the code snippet, but this is normally doable by searching through the docs and trying out different properties.